# Find object by index by findIndex and if nothing found return first item

Tags: javascript

The function `findIndex` will return the index of the element, if there is a found in the list or it will return `-1`

But, if nothing was found, I want to have an existing fixed item, i.e. the first one, instead of checking the return value:

```
if (id === -1)
  id = 0;
```

Is there a easy, or shorter way in JavaScript?

```js
var items = [{
  message: 'Hello World',
  day: 'j1'
}, {
  message: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit',
  day: 'j2'
}]

function idbyDay(day) {
  return this.items.findIndex(q => q.day === day);
}

function myFunction() {
    var day = document.getElementById("day").value
  console.log(day);
  var id = this.idbyDay(day);
  if (id === -1)
    id = 0;
  console.log(this.items[id]);
}
```

```html
<input id="day" value="no"><button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: It does not return the id; it returns the index.

Comment: Please post the relevant code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator, but you can't simplify it much more.

```
function idbyDay(day) {
  const idx = this.items.findIndex(q => q.day === day)
  return idx !== -1 ? idx : 0;
}
```

Alternatively, since you are only using the index to get the item from the array, you can use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) with the nullish coalescing operator to provide a default value.

```
function itembyDay(day) {
  return this.items.find(q => q.day === day) ?? this.items[0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful, because the ternary operator was new to me

Comment: @andpei Happy to help.